# Access train and evaluation error in xgboost

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I started using python `xgboost` backage. Is there a way to get training and validation errors at each training epoch? I can't find one in the [documentation](https://xgboost.readthedocs.org/en/latest/python/index.html#contents)

Have trained a simple model and got output:

> [09:17:37] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots,
>   124 extra nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=6
>
> [0]   eval-rmse:0.407474  train-rmse:0.346349 [09:17:37]
>   src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 116 extra
>   nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=6
>
> [1](https://xgboost.readthedocs.org/en/latest/python/index.html#contents)   eval-rmse:0.410902  train-rmse:0.339925 [09:17:38]
>   src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 124 extra
>   nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=6
>
> [2]   eval-rmse:0.413563  train-rmse:0.335941 [09:17:38]
>   src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 126 extra
>   nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=6
>
> [3]   eval-rmse:0.418412  train-rmse:0.333071 [09:17:38]
>   src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 114 extra
>   nodes, 0 pruned nodes, max_depth=6

However I need to pass these `eval-rmse` and `train-rmse` further in code or at least plot these curves.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One way to save your intermediate results is by passing `evals_result` argument to `xgb.train` method.

Let's say you have created a `train` and an `eval` matrix in XGB format, and have initialized some parameters `params` for XGBoost (In my case, `params = {'max_depth':2, 'eta':1, 'silent':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic' }`).

1. Create an empty dict

   `progress = dict()`
2. Create a watchlist, (I guess you already have it given that you are printing train-rmse)

   `watchlist  = [(train,'train-rmse'), (eval, 'eval-rmse')]`
3. Pass these to `xgb.train`

   `bst = xgb.train(param, train, 10, watchlist, evals_result=progress)`

At the end of iteration, the `progress` dictionary will contain the desired train/validation errors

```
> print progress
{'train-rmse': {'error': ['0.50000', ....]}, 'eval-rmse': { 'error': ['0.5000',....]}}
```

Comment: Thanks, very clear and helpful!
In the version I am using the progress dictionary has different keys though

Answer (score 2):

@MaxPY, this is in reply to your comment on Sudeep Juvekar's answer above: the keys for your progress dictionary is set to whatever string you pass as the second argument to the watchlist. For instance,

```
watchlist  = [(train,'train-rmse-demo'), (eval, 'eval-rmse-demo')]
```

sets the dictionary keys to `train-rmse-demo` and `eval-rmse-demo`