# Save the output of xgb.train of XGBoost as a log file with python logging

Tags: python, logging, xgboost

I tried to save the output of `xgb.train` of XGBoost as a log file by `logging`, but I could not record the output. How can I record it? I tried to refer to the existing Stackoverflow question but it was impossible. I would like you to show it with a concrete sample.

```python
import sys
import logging

# ---------------------------------------------- #
# Some logging settings
# ---------------------------------------------- #

import xgboost as xgb

import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits

rng = np.random.RandomState(31337)

print("Zeros and Ones from the Digits dataset: binary classification")
digits = load_digits(2)
y = digits['target']
X = digits['data']
kf = KFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=rng)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):

    param = {'max_depth':2, 'eta':0.3, 'silent':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic' }

    dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X[train_index], y[train_index])
    dtest = xgb.DMatrix(X[test_index], y[test_index])

    # specify validations set to watch performance
    watchlist  = [(dtest,'eval'), (dtrain,'train')]
    num_round = 2
    bst = xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round, watchlist)

# I want to record this output.
# Zeros and Ones from the Digits dataset: binary classification
# [0]   eval-error:0.011111 train-error:0.011111
# [1]   eval-error:0.011111 train-error:0.005556
# [0]   eval-error:0.016667 train-error:0.005556
# [1]   eval-error:0.005556 train-error:0
```

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197799/access-train-and-evaluation-error-in-xgboost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The accepted solution does not work with xgboost version 1.3 and above**. (Tested on 1.6.1), due to following:

In XGBoost 1.3, a new callback interface is designed for Python package.

(Source: https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/callbacks.html)

You can achieve **python logging for xgboost.train by defining custom logging callback** and passing it as argument to xgb.train as shown below:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

import xgboost

class XGBLogging(xgboost.callback.TrainingCallback):
    """log train logs to file"""

    def __init__(self, epoch_log_interval=100):
        self.epoch_log_interval = epoch_log_interval

    def after_iteration(self, model, epoch, evals_log):
        if epoch % self.epoch_log_interval == 0:
            for data, metric in evals_log.items():
                metrics = list(metric.keys())
                metrics_str = ""
                for m_key in metrics:
                    metrics_str = metrics_str + f"{m_key}: {metric[m_key][-1]}"
                logger.info(f"Epoch: {epoch}, {data}: {metrics_str}")
        # False to indicate training should not stop.
        return False

model = xgboost.train(
                xgboost_parms, 
                dtrain=dtrain,
                evals=[(dtrain,"train"),(dvalid,"valid")]
                callbacks=[XGBLogging(epoch_log_interval=100)]
            )
```

Answer (score 5):

xgboost prints their log into standard output directly and you cannot change the behaviour.
But `callbacks` parameter of `xgb.train` has ability to record the result as same timing as internal prints.

Following code is a sample using callback to record xgboost log into logger.
`log_evaluation()` returns a callback function called from xgboost internal and you can add the callback function to `callbacks`

```
from logging import getLogger, basicConfig, INFO

import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

# Some logging settings
basicConfig(level=INFO)
logger = getLogger(__name__)


def log_evaluation(period=1, show_stdv=True):
    """Create a callback that logs evaluation result with logger.

    Parameters
    ----------
    period : int
        The period to log the evaluation results

    show_stdv : bool, optional
         Whether show stdv if provided

    Returns
    -------
    callback : function
        A callback that logs evaluation every period iterations into logger.
    """

    def _fmt_metric(value, show_stdv=True):
        """format metric string"""
        if len(value) == 2:
            return '%s:%g' % (value[0], value[1])
        elif len(value) == 3:
            if show_stdv:
                return '%s:%g+%g' % (value[0], value[1], value[2])
            else:
                return '%s:%g' % (value[0], value[1])
        else:
            raise ValueError("wrong metric value")

    def callback(env):
        if env.rank != 0 or len(env.evaluation_result_list) == 0 or period is False:
            return
        i = env.iteration
        if i % period == 0 or i + 1 == env.begin_iteration or i + 1 == env.end_iteration:
            msg = '\t'.join([_fmt_metric(x, show_stdv) for x in env.evaluation_result_list])
            logger.info('[%d]\t%s\n' % (i, msg))

    return callback


rng = np.random.RandomState(31337)

print("Zeros and Ones from the Digits dataset: binary classification")
digits = load_digits(2)
y = digits['target']
X = digits['data']
kf = KFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=rng)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    param = {'max_depth': 2, 'eta': 0.3, 'silent': 1, 'objective': 'binary:logistic'}

    dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X[train_index], y[train_index])
    dtest = xgb.DMatrix(X[test_index], y[test_index])

    # specify validations set to watch performance
    watchlist = [(dtest, 'eval'), (dtrain, 'train')]
    num_round = 2
    # add logger
    callbacks = [log_evaluation(1, True)]
    bst = xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round, watchlist, callbacks=callbacks)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
%logstart -o "test.log"
sys.stdout = open('test.log', 'a')

import xgboost as xgb

import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits

rng = np.random.RandomState(31337)

print("Zeros and Ones from the Digits dataset: binary classification")
digits = load_digits(2)
y = digits['target']
X = digits['data']
kf = KFold(n_splits=2, shuffle=True, random_state=rng)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):

    param = {'max_depth':2, 'eta':0.3, 'silent':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic' }

    dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X[train_index], y[train_index])
    dtest = xgb.DMatrix(X[test_index], y[test_index])

    # specify validations set to watch performance
    watchlist  = [(dtest,'eval'), (dtrain,'train')]
    num_round = 2
    bst = xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round, watchlist)
```

This will start saving everything in the file test.log. The output as well as the input.